# C++ maximum non negative int

Tags: c++

Is the following going to work as expected on all platforms, sizes of int, etc? Or is there a more accepted way of doing it? (I made the following up.)

```
#define MAX_NON_NEGATIVE_INT ((int)(((unsigned int)-1) / 2))
```

I won't insult your intelligence by explaining what it's doing!

Edit: I should have mentioned that I cannot use any standard classes, because I'm running without the C runtime.

Comment: What's wrong with using `INT_MAX` from `<climits>`?

Comment: This ugly #define could become a nice #include, as suggested below, and solve your problem.

Comment: On my system, INT_MAX is defined as "#define INT_MAX       2147483647". 2147483647 is what I also get from my define above. But what happens if the size of an int is not 32 bits on the target system?

Comment: on the 64-bits target system it will be defined appropriately in `<climits>`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't want to use defines (and you want a standard way of calculating the limits), then do this:

```
#include <limits>
std::numeric_limits<int>::min()
```

These are the ANSI standard defines in limits.h:

```
#define INT_MIN     (-2147483647 - 1) /* minimum (signed) int value */
#define INT_MAX       2147483647    /* maximum (signed) int value */
#define UINT_MAX      0xffffffff    /* maximum unsigned int value */
```

These are the defines from BaseTsd.h:

```
#define MAXUINT     ((UINT)~((UINT)0))
#define MAXINT      ((INT)(MAXUINT >> 1))
#define MININT      ((INT)~MAXINT)
```

Comment: I'm running VS2005 and MAXINT isn't defined anywhere in the headers! The closest in BaseTsd.h is MAXINT_PTR, but no banana. However, the _PTR versions I do have do almost the same as the above. More importantly, the above does exactly what my original define does except it does ">> 1" where I do "/ 2". The only difference is that I've mangled the MAXINT and MAXUINT together!

Comment: These are the wrong macros: http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/limits.html Also since this is a C++ question you should lead with numeric_limits

Answer (score 11):

There is [a standard way to this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/limits/numeric_limits/):

```
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>

cout << numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max();
```

Being standard, this is guaranteed to be portable across all platforms.

Comment: You should note that `numeric_limits` will not give you constant expression. So you can't write, for instance, `enum X { x1 = std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max() };`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <climits>


INT_MAX
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the class `numeric_limits`, included in the standard library.

See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/limits/numeric_limits/).

Answer (score 0):

I would modify what you supplied just slightly, since you are coding C++ and not C.

```
const int MAXINT =(int)(((unsigned int)-1) >> 1), MININT = -MAXINT -1;
```

I prefer the right shift over the divide by 2, though they do the same thing, because bit shifting is more suggestive of the bit mangling used to generate MAXINT.

MAXINT yields the same thing as you'd get by using

```
#include <limits>
    const int OFFICIALMAXINT = numeric_limits<int>::max();
```

MININT yields the same thing as you'd get by using

```
#include <limits>
    const int OFFICIALMININT = numeric_limits<int>::min();
```

Hardcoding these values, as some above suggested, is a baaad idea.

I prefer the bit mangling, because I know it is always correct and I don't have to rely on remembering the library and the syntax of the call, but it does come down to a matter of preference.